# HAProxy rewrite of host and path

Tags: haproxy

this should be a pretty simple rewrite rule, but I can't get it working. I want to rewrite Request as follows:

```
http://acme.org/FOO/BAR
```

to

```
http://FOO.acme.org/BAR
```

`FOO` is some simple string in this case and `BAR` should match the rest of the URL. It seems as `reqrep` does not allow the rewrite of the host :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

But nowadays it's better to replace host with

```
http-request replace-header Host .* FOO.acme.org
```

since reqirep is [deprecated](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#4.2-http-request) since haproxy 1.6.

Comment: Thank you for updating this, `reqirep` seems not to be deprecated in 1.6, but now sure is: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#4-reqirep

Comment: "Using "reqadd"/"reqdel"/"reqrep" to manipulate request headers is discouraged
in newer versions (>= 1.5)."

Comment: If you want to replace `.*`, then just use `http-request set-header Host FOO.acme.org`

Comment: @rustyx: nope. Not working for me with HAProxy 1.7.9. It keeps requesting my default backend, ends up in a 404, and tells my browser that the other server answered that... but that's not right, it's just a masquerade of Host.

Answer (score 6):

You can rewrite the host with `reqrep`, try this:

```
acl match path_end -i /FOO/BAR
reqirep ^Host: Host:\ FOO.acme.org if match
```